# spring-cloud-contrac with spring-jms

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

Are there any examples on how to integrate spring-cloud-contract with plain spring-jms lib? In my project, unfortunately, I cannot use spring-cloud-stream and I am stuck with plain JMS (JMSListener, JMSTemplate). Are those two project can be used together in testing?

Thanks for help!